# Which to use for SVN tag?

Tags: svn

User A commits into SVN with r1234.
A few users after him also checked in with the resulting HEAD at r1250.
We are told to tag a trunk of last ci at r1234.

Which do we use for tagging properly and safely ?

```
svn copy http://some.url.com/some/dir@1234 http://some.url.com/some/other/dir
or
svn copy -r 1234 http://some.url.com/some/dir http://some.url.com/some/other/dir
```

We think there's a difference in the meaning of each.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Definitions: `@1234` is called the *peg revision* and `-r 1234` is called the *operative revision*. If the peg revision is not specified, it defaults to `HEAD` (for remote operations). If the operative revision is not specified, it defaults to the peg revision.

What's the difference between the following two commands?

```
svn cp -r 1234 ^/trunk@1234 ^/branches/foobar
svn cp -r 1234 ^/trunk@HEAD ^/branches/foobar
```

The former copies the directory with the name `/trunk` in revision 1234. In contract the latter starts with the directory named `/trunk` in the newest revision, determines the ancestor in revision 1234 and copies that directory.

That means there can only be a difference, if the directory `/trunk` has been renamed after revision 1234. That's unlikely. However:

**Use the peg revision to create a branch, because it always has the same effect regardless of what happened in the repository after the specified revision.**

```
svn cp ^/trunk@1234 ^/branches/foobar
```

See the section [Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) in the online book [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html) for further information.